# Notepad++ Add sequential numbers in front of unordered specific lines

Tags: notepad++

I'm looking for a way to make the text into the list by adding sequential numbers at a beginning of those lines that start with specific text, certain symbols. Here's an example:

Current text:

```
Lala text
text
Lala text
```

Required text:

```
1Lala text
text
2Lala text
```

Comment: Likely, the simplest way to do this is to use another tool. As far as I am aware, the Column Editor in Notepad++ currently doesn't support working with Find/Replace regular expressions (nor does Column Editing seem to allow selecting only certain lines to apply Column Editor changes to i.e. changes must be done in a block). The exception to this might be if you wrote your own script for the Python plugin in Notepad++ (at which point, another tool might be simpler again anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using a combination of RegEx (to do it at the beginning of the line with a specific keyword) and the Column Editor (to add an incremental number, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428620/regular-expression-notepad-increment-numbers-in-every-line)). But it might be easier to use a script language, e.g. if you know a bit of VBA to write Excel macros.

PS. there is a way to do it [just in RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942634) but it's not pretty.

Note: superuser is not a scripting service you should give it a try yourself first. Just add another question if you run in to a **specific** problem you can not solve yourself.

Comment: it would be nice to include some info on how to improve the answer with the downvote, thx.